# my sql select where clause date

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, date-format

I just want to create query statement where date format (%d-%m-%Y)

like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION
 WHERE DATE(date_Transaction) = DATE_FORMAT('19-04-1994', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

but the result is

> Empty set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT * FROM `TRANSACTION`
WHERE DATE(date_Transaction) = STR_TO_DATE('19-04-1994', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: thanks for help me and edit my post. i'm noob at here at this is my first question at stackoverflow :)